# Code before the first 'case' in a switch-statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

In C it's possible to write code before the first `case` label. Are there any cases for which it is useful to do this or is it just a 'dead block of code' ?

E.g.:

```
switch (...)    {
  {
    int a = 0x2a;
    printf("%d\n", a);
  }
  case 0:
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried a lot of different examples and the one above is just to clarify. But there's always a chance that I missed a feature of (GNU) C and something can be done in this region.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It can be useful to declare variables that have a scope limited to the `switch` block (but be aware that any initialisers for those variables will be skipped):

```
switch (...)
{
    int n;

    case 0:
    ...
}
```

In theory, you could also put code there that you get to using `goto`.

Comment: If you want a variable in  this scope, start a block just before the switch and declare the variable in there, i.e. enclose the whole switch statement in another set of brackets. Declaring it inside switch but not in a case doesn't work.

Comment: @Martin: Variable declarations *do* work as they don't produce any output code; they're merely there for the compiler to note “Ah, I know this variable, I've seen it back there”.

Comment: "any initialisers for those variables may be skipped" - is it even that simple (the initializer is either skipped or isn't), or is it undefined behaviour/ill-formed program to jump over an initializer? I can't remember.

Comment: Did you seriously suggest the use of `goto`? I thought that was extremely bad practice.

Comment: @Arc676 That's a common misconception, even among experienced programmers. It began with a good paper by Dijkstra, but as Steele points out in "Debunking the 'Expensive Procedure Call' Myth", goto itself is not bad, but abuse of goto is. Steele: "[W]e sought to eliminate unwanted concepts and programming styles by banning a construct." Goto can be used well, but is best used very sparingly. As he also points out, other control structures can be used to write obfuscated code if sufficiently abused. The bottom line is to avoid confusing code (easily written with goto), not simply goto itself.

Answer (score 21):

I think this is less a feature than an artifact of how C treats `switch`/`case`—as just a series of jump targets without restrictions on the syntax. That's why [Duff's device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) works and that's also why the code before the first `case` won't ever run.

If you look at the generated assembly you'll see that the code will just be jumped over:

```
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR _x$[ebp]
    mov DWORD PTR tv64[ebp], ecx
    cmp DWORD PTR tv64[ebp], 0                  ; here begins the switch
    je  SHORT $LN1@main                         ; jump to case 0
    jmp SHORT $LN4@main                         ; jump out of the switch
; Line 8
    mov DWORD PTR _a$752[ebp], 42
; Line 9
    mov edx, DWORD PTR _a$752[ebp]              ; here we have the dead code
    push    edx
    push    OFFSET $SG754
    call    _printf
    add esp, 8
$LN1@main:                                      ; and here case 0
; Line 12
    push    OFFSET $SG756
    call    _printf
    add esp, 4
$LN4@main:
; Line 15
    xor eax, eax
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
```

Answer (score 16):

The C standard document has an example that explains exactly the behavior of this type of construct (6.8.4.2/7 "The switch statement"):

> EXAMPLE    In the artiﬁcial program fragment
>
> ```
> switch (expr)
> {
>     int i = 4;
>     f(i);
> case 0:
>     i  =  17;
>     /*  falls through into default code  */
> default:
>     printf("%d\n", i);
> }
> ```
>
> the object whose identifier is `i` exists with automatic storage duration (within the  block)  but  is  never initialized, and thus if the controlling expression has a nonzero value, the call to the `printf` function will access an indeterminate value.  Similarly, the call to the function `f` cannot be reached.

So even though this is permitted, it's easily one of those "just because you can doesn't mean you should" situations.  The construct is confusing and can easily lead to using an uninitialized variable since it can be very unclear whether and where the initialization occurs.

Comment: C standard document can be found at: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/wg14/www/docs/n1336.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what your after. Why not just put the code before the case?

```
int a = 0x2a;
printf("%d\n", a);
switch (...)    {
case 0:
...
}
```

Isn't that the same as what you intend ? (apart from in your example the code would never run if the compiler doesn't complain.)

Comment: The printf in my example was chosen randomly.

Comment: does it matter? questions should be asked of everything