# About switch case in C, why it does not print out?

Tags: c, switch-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Code before the first ‘case’ in a switch-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101393/code-before-the-first-case-in-a-switch-statement)

I have the following set of code in C:

```
void isFindValue(int value1, int value2)
{
    switch (value1)
    {
    case 1:
      printf("value1 is found!\n");
      break;

    case 2:
      printf("value1 is found!\n");
      break;

    case 3:
      switch(value2)
      {
    printf("aaaaaaaaaaaaa\n");
     case 6:
         printf("bbbbbbbbbbbb\n");
         printf("value2 is found!\n");
         break;
      }
     default:
     break;    
}
```

if I call the function as is isFindValue(3,6); the printf of `bbbbbbbbbbbb` show up, but `aaaaaaaaaaaaa` does not, why this will happen? should we not do something before the case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2102434/1233508

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `switch ()` works using labels. It jumps to the label of which the condition is satisfied. So when reaching

```
switch(value2) {
    printf("aaaaaaaaaaaaa\n");
    case 6:
```

the control flow immediately jumps to the label `case 6:` so that it skips the call to `printf()`.

The solution would be placing it correctly, outside of the inner switch:

```
case 3:
    printf("aaaaa\n");
    switch (value2) {
```

etc.

Comment: Yes, another reason why labels should be avoided (or at least consumed moderately).

Comment: Why does this provide an argument against using labels (and therefor switch-case statements), H2CO3?

Comment: @Joost Because labels are easy to abuse (just like in this case). Also, generally speaking, labels don't represent a good style when you can have nice structured control-flow statements such as `if` or various loops. Consider the point of the "while vs. goto begin" debate.

Comment: The while v goto debate has nothing to do with the switch-case. Are you're saying the switch statement should be pulled because there's an if construction available?

Comment: @Joost Well, that's quite radical, but if you wish so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

"aaaaaaaaaaaaa" is not showing up because it is misplaced (it's not contained in a label so it is unreachable). You need to move it up to before the second switch statement:

```
case 3:
    printf("aaaaaaaaaaaaa\n");
    switch(value2)
    {
        // body
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to the `printf` function in the statement :

```
printf("aaaaaaaaaaaaa\n");
```

cannot be reached because it is before the first `case` statement of the second `switch`.

see [Code before the first 'case' in a switch-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101393/code-before-the-first-case-in-a-switch-statement/2102434#2102434)

Answer (score 0):

"aaaaaaaaaaaaa\n" is not being printed within any `case`. Your code is not properly structured.

Try moving the statement out of the `switch` block like this:

```
printf("aaaaaaaaaaaaa\n");
switch(value2)
{
    case 6:
        printf("bbbbbbbbbbbb\n");
        printf("value2 is found!\n");
        break;
}
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

switch always look for `case` and that's why `aaaaaaaaaaaa` was skipped. It will execute the statement of related `case` block.