# Javascript scope variable to switch case?

Tags: javascript, scope, switch-statement

In C you can scope a variable to a switch case, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2101514/773263).

With javascript I get unexpected token using the following:

```js
const i = 1

switch (i) {
    // variables scoped to switch
    var s
    var x = 2342
    case 0:
      s = 1 + x
      break
    case 1:
      s = 'b'
      break
}
```

Is there another way to do this or should I just declare my variables outside the switch?

EDIT:

This is a workaround I considered but it didn't end up working. The reason being that each case has its own scope.

```js
const i = 1

switch (i) {
    case i:
      // variables scoped to switch
      var s
      var x = 2342
    case 0:
      s = 1 + x
      break
    case 1:
      s = 'b'
      break
}
```

Comment: Your `switch` statement is invalid in `JS` at least. You can define variables inside the cases or outside switch.

Comment: Since clearly you want to access `s` after, outside the `switch`, why are you trying to scope it to within the `switch` statement…?!

Comment: @deceze this is only an example case there are many reasons one would want to do this.

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride See my updated answer for a workaround that gives you what you are looking for.

Comment: @deceze maybe there isn't a lot of reasons to do this. I was actually just trying to make someones code pass jslint (var declared multiple times once for each case) without changing their scope. Looking back it's probably better to just change the scope or ignore rather than making the code harder to understand.

Comment: It is as easy as using `{  code  }` inside the switch

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since `var` creates variables at *function* scope anyway, using it is pretty pointless. For this to work at a granularity below function scopes you'll have to use `let` and a browser/compiler which supports it, and then introduce a new block which you *can* scope things to (within `switch` it's simply invalid syntax):

```
if (true) {
    let s;

    switch (i) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This scopes `s` to the `if` block, which for all intents and purposes is identical to the "`switch` scope" here.

If you cannot support `let`, you'll need to use an IIFE:

```
(function () {
    var s;

    switch (...) ...
})();
```

Comment: The first example doesn't need the `if` at all. Just wrap the code in `{}`.

Comment: I'm unsure in what situations that may be interpreted as an object literal, so I suggested the safe `if` statement. Sure, you can try it without that.

Comment: I already have tried it. It is perfectly legal. Just as the branches of your `if` won't be confused for an object literal, surrounding the entire block wouldn't be either.

Comment: `{}` in a `case` is valid as mentioned in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch#block-scope_variables_within_switch_statements)

Answer (score 98):

some alternative:

```
/* curly braces inside the case */

const i = 1

switch (i) {
  case 0: {
    let x = 2342;
    let s = 1 + x;
    console.log(x+' & '+s+' from inside');
  } break;
  case 1: {
    let x = 2342;
    let s = 'b';
    console.log(x+' & '+s+' from inside'); /* 2342 & b from inside */
  } break;
}

console.log(x+' & '+s+' from outside'); /* Uncaught ReferenceError */
```

or

```
/* curly braces outside the switch */

const i = 1

{
  let x = 2342;
  let s;
  switch (i) {
    case 0:
      s = 1 + x;
      break;
    case 1:
      s = 'b';
      break;
  }
  console.log(x+' & '+s+' from inside'); /* 2342 & b from inside */
}

console.log(x+' & '+s+' from outside'); /* Uncaught ReferenceError */
```

Comment: This seems like an obvious miss by the TC39 committee.

Comment: @pdoherty926 yeah, like what te heck :D

Answer (score 3):

No, this is invalid syntax. A `case` or `default` statement is expected within a `switch`. You can check the specification here: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.11

You can also try entering your code in a JSLinter and see that this an error: http://jslint.com/

```
Expected 'case' and instead saw 'var'.
```

The workaround that you're considering would be the same thing as putting them outside the switch statement. Remember, `var` has *function*-level scope, **not** block-level scope. That means they are bound to the entire function containing the switch. You should declare them outside of the switch because that is where they are accessible.

```
const i = 1;
var s;
var x = 2342;

switch (i) {
  case 0:
    s = 1 + x;
    break;
  case 1:
    s = 'b';
    break;
  default:
    break;
}

console.log("s is " + s);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript defines 3 levels of scope:

- **Global** - Anything not delcared in a function
- **Function** - Anything declared in a function using the `var` keyword
- **Block**  - Anything declared in a block container (`{}`) using `let`

**So, to creae a scope an entire construct, you have two choices: Function or Block**

> In order to get the the behavior you are looking for with a function:

```js
const i = 1

function doSwitch(data){

  // variables are not scoped to switch, but are 
  // scoped to the function, which only contains 
  // the switch.
  var s;
  var x = 2342;
  
  switch (data) {
    case 0:
      s = 1 + x;
      break;
    case 1:
      s = 'b';
      break;
    default:
      s = "other";
  }

  console.log("s is " + s)

}

doSwitch(18);
```

> Or, in order to get the functionality with a block using [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

```js
const i = 1;

// Wrapping the switch in its own block allows for let to work:
{
      // variables are not scoped to switch, but are 
      // scoped to the function, which only contains 
      // the switch.
      let s;
      let x = 2342;
      
      switch (i) {
        case 0:
          s = 1 + x;
          break;
        case 1:
          s = 'b';
          break;
        default:
          s = "other";
      }

      console.log("s is " + s)
}

// Test:
console.log(s, x);  // ReferenceError
```

Comment: You can't declare it in the middle of a switch which is what the question is

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Yep, thanks. Didn't catch that at first. Answer has been modified.

Answer (score 0):

It should be declared outside the switch. The below might help:

```
var i = 1, x = 2342;
var s;
switch (i)
 {        
    case 0:
      s = 1 + x;
      break;
    case 1:
      s = 'b';
      break;
}
console.log("s is " + s);
```