# Code before first case in switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

*Please note that this is a question about C++ language, not about how real or useful is the example I'm giving to illustrate it.*

Imagine we have an `enum` in a namespace (or namespaces):

```
namespace SomeVeryLargeNamespaceExample {
    enum class E {
        One,
        Two,
    };
}
```

Now, we want to use it in the expression of a `switch` statement. Today I found that it is possible to add the `using SomeVeryLargeNamespaceExample::E` inside the `switch` statement, before the first `case`, reducing the code cluttering in the `case`s:

```
switch (e) {
    using SomeVeryLargeNamespaceExample::E;
case E::One:
    std::cout << "One\n";
    break;
case E::Two:
    std::cout << "Two\n";
    break;
}
```

At first glance I thought it was some kind of "do this before any case statement" feature that I never learned about, but some expressions, such as a function call, are not executed (actually, gcc generates a warning `statement will never be executed [-Wswitch-unreachable]`). On the other hand, a variable declaration is possible (but not initialization).

My question is, **what other statements are possible? Is this a feature or just a *consequence* of how `switch` is designed?**

Note: I found [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2101393/1485885), but it is specific for C (so it doesn't mention the namespaces case, for example), and I'm curious about C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any valid C++ statement is possible:

```
int a;

void foo(int x)
{
    switch (x) {
        a=4;
    case 0:
        a=1;
        break;
    case 1:
        a=2;
        break;
    }
}
```

This is syntactically valid C++, and gcc has no issues compiling it and producing an executable. However the initial statement can never be reached, of course. Therefore every modern C++ compiler will give you a warning message:

> t.C: In function ‘void foo(int)’:
>
> t.C:8:18: warning: statement will
> never be executed [-Wswitch-unreachable]
>
> ```
> 8 |                 a=4;
>   |
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to know which statements will have _effect_ (as the _using_ in the example)? I assume those that won't generate actual code but will _guide_ compiler, aren't they?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. There is no master list, of some kind, of which C++ statements do not generate code. But as you continue to learn C++ you will learn what each one is.

Comment: @cbuchart • it could be using for practical purposes with [Duff's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device), putting the `do {` before the first `case`.